# AngularJS 1.3.0 input date type seems incorrect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I seem to be having some issues with angular 1.3.0-rc4 and the input type date.
I have set up a plunker to try and illustrate my problem http://plnkr.co/edit/6YeNKhfigDAqv14XNHfI?p=preview

The issue seems to be when using 1.3.0-rc4, the value from the date input field seems to be incorrect by 1 day?

When the date 19/07/1982 (dd/MM/yyyy) is entered into the input field the following value is set in the model:

```
{"date": "1982-07-18T12:00:00.000Z"}
```

Yet when 1.2.x is used, the following is set in the model:

```
{"date": "1982-07-19"}
```

Is this an issue with the release candidate? Or am I missing something obvious?

**Updates**

Have tested this in both Chrome v37.x and IE11 and same result. Unsure why the value is midnight of the day before?

Comment: than plunker works for me

Comment: @DanielA.White so using 1.3.0 you are able to get `{"date": "1982-07-19T12:00:00.000Z"}` ?

Comment: no i get the utc time for my midnight.

Comment: @DanielA.White so any idea why in 1.3.0 it gives me midnight of the previous day in UTC?

Comment: @DanielA.White Chrome v37.x